# array valiu to a singl element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a math problem where I take a number e.g. var num1= [1,2,4,3];
and then concentrate the number into a single number  e.g. var num2 =(1243) . Does anyone know how to do it .?

num1= [1,2,4,3];
covert to
num2 =(1243)

Comment: What's your approach?

Comment: That's an array of numbers btw - it might affect how you approach the problem.

Comment: look for Array.join and parseInt to find your way

Comment: do you have always a digit in the array? what is with negative values?

Answer (score 1):

```
const num1= [1,2,4,3];
const num = parseInt(num1.join(''));
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score -2):

The best pratice is to use **Array.join()** methods. For Example:

```
let arr = ["Hello", "Random", "Word"];
console.log(arr.join('')) //Output: "HelloRandomWord"
```

You can join the elements of an array into a string without using the Array.join() method by using a for loop

```
let arr = ["Hello", "Random", "Word"];
let result = "";

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result += arr[i];
}

console.log(result);  // Output: "HelloRandomWord"
```

Alternatively, you can use the **Array.reduce()** method to concatenate the elements of the array:

```
let arr = ["Hello", "Random", "Word"];
let result = arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);

console.log(result);  // Output: "HelloRandomWord"
```

Comment: This does not answer the already closed question